# Cannot install Netbeans on Solaris

Tags: solaris, netbeans-8

My problem is that I cannot install netbeans IDE 8 on Solaris 11. I love solaris, and NetBeans website tells that is possible to install it on Solaris, but I get the folowing error:

```
Cannot setup embedded JVM
This most likely is because the embedded JVM is incompatible with the current system.
```

Comment: What bundle did you download?  None of the download options at https://netbeans.org/downloads/ show a Solaris option.  Solaris isn't even listed as a possible platform.

Comment: When I entered the download section, I saw that it has no Solaris option, so I just downloaded the linux blunde.

Comment: Download and install JDK 8 (not JRE, which is probably already installed, and not 9) for Solaris. Current version is 8u162. Then download and install the Platform-Independent Zip netbeans package. Full instructions at https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/install.html#install_zip .

Comment: Worked!! Thank you guy!